# Почему при выполнении команды gulp sass выдает ошибку?

Tags: windows, gulp

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста, как решить возникушую проблему. Вот я даю команду в файле *gulpfile.js*:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
sass = require('gulp-sass');
gulp.task('sass', function(){ 
  return gulp.src('app/sass/main.sass') 
  .pipe(sass()) 
  .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
});
```

Документ *main.sass* уже создан. Идем в командную строку и вводим `gulp sass`. Далее происходит ошибка:

> module.js 583 return process.dlopen(path._makeLong(filename));
>   Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
>   \?\C:\Users\j-ku2\Desktop\MyProject\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-48\binding.node

Подскажите, что с этим делать? Второй день маюсь.

Comment: А как устанавливали, npm i --save-dev gulp-sass?
У меня такую же проблему решила установка  npm i --save-dev gulp-sass@beta !